# How to declare a new class to the global space from within a namespace'd file?

Tags: php, namespaces, global

or to be completely concise with my question:

*( Within a Namespace'd file )* is it possible to declare a new class *( that extends a class defined in the global namespace )* to the global space?

### For example

```
namespace Roots\Sage\VisualComposer;
...

...
if ( class_exists( '\\WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
    class WPBakeryShortCode_Your_Gallery extends \WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {}
}
```

#### Some debug info

```
echo 'x: ' . WPBakeryShortCodesContainer::class . PHP_EOL;

echo 'y: ' . WPBakeryShortCode_Your_Gallery::class . PHP_EOL;
```

Returns:

```
x: WPBakeryShortCodesContainer

y: Roots\Sage\VisualComposer\WPBakeryShortCode_Your_Gallery
```

So my new class of `WPBakeryShortCode_Your_Gallery` is in the `Roots\Sage\VisualComposer` namespace, not the global...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternative syntax for namespaces:

```
namespace Roots\Sage\VisualComposer {
  //...    
}
//...
namespace Roots\Sage\VisualEditor {
  //...    
}
//...
namespace {  // global code
  if ( class_exists( '\\WPBakeryShortCodesContainer' ) ) {
    class WPBakeryShortCode_Your_Gallery extends \WPBakeryShortCodesContainer {}
  }
}
```

More: [Defining multiple namespaces in the same file](http://php.net/manual/language.namespaces.definitionmultiple.php)